# Image generation on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm developing a webpage that displays output from a numerical model that I am running. I'm looking to take user input (latitude/longitude coordinates specifically), use php or something similar to call a python script which takes these coordinates as input and produces a png image, and then show the resultant png back to the user.

Is there any framework or anything to do this? I'm mainly looking for pointers on displaying the image to the user.

Comment: If you want to call a script from your web page (javascript), you should set up a web server (in php or python) that let you an API endpoint. Then you can call this HTTP URL with your parameters like `mydomain.com/script.php?latitude=X&longitude=Y`. You should read about ajax (that's the way javascrit calls HTTP URL) https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could display an image after a form has been submitted using javascript.

```
 <body id="body">
    <!-- Add a form to take in latitude/longitude coordinates here -->  
    <button onclick = "addImage()"> Click to Generate Image</button>     
    <script>            
        function addImage() { 
            //Call function here to generate image from form imput
            var img = document.createElement('img'); 
            //insert path to generated image below
            img.src =  'https://source.unsplash.com/xJsE87_f78s'; 
            document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);  
        }  
    </script>  
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Would there be any way to only display this image to the specific user who requested it, and have it not be visible to others?

Comment: @SlushP22 that happen through a serverside code that depends on your language of choice, authorization is the name. in php for example there is zen framework, or ruby on rails for ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I think the google map library has every you want in it, you should check it out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial. gl.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Yii2 ([Yii2 Framework](https://www.yiiframework.com/)). It is very easy to use and fast enough to setup and understand. They have an easy introductory tutorial and with that you can create a webpage that allows users to login in and, after being logged in, to post a form with the coordinates that you can manipulate in php and python to show the image.

The thing is that you would need to learn some basic knowledge in VMC architecture (View, Model, Controller) while learning about the framework, which would take at least 1-3 weeks. But it would help you a lot for any web future project.